# How to implement arriving behavior with time delta?

Tags: javascript, physics

I'm trying to create an autonomous agent with arriving behaviour based on Reynolds classic Boids paper and more specifically Dan Shiffman's implementation on natureofcode.com. Both of these approaches are easy to understand (and work) but they both assume a fixed nominal update step rather than querying the elapsed time since the last frame update and applying this time delta during the Euler integration step. Ie they suggest simply:

```
//pseudocode
acceleration.add(force);
velocity.add(acceleration);
location.add(velocity);
```

however if I want to include a time delta then various physics papers suggest I should rewrite this as:

```
//pseudocode
delta = timeElpasedSinceLastFrameUpdate();
acceleration.add(force);
deltaAcceleration = acceleration.mult(delta);
velocity.add(deltaAcceleration );
deltaVelocity = velocity.mult(delta);
location.add(deltaVelocity);
```

This also works until I try to implement the steering behaviours and specifically the arriving behaviour. For reference to the methodology see example 6.2 in the link here:

[Nature of Code Steering Behaviours](http://natureofcode.com/book/chapter-6-autonomous-agents/)

The problematic step (in pseudocode) is steeringForce = desired - velocity;

Without a time delta applied the contribution of '- velocity' to the steering force correctly counteracts the currently held velocity vector and brings the object to a decelerating stop at the arrival destination.

With a time delta applied however the steeringForce is effectively moderated by the fractional time delta when I multiply acceleration by delta and hence doesn't apply sufficient deceleration to the accumulated velocity to bring the object to a halt in time and I get oscillating behaviour.

I can 'fix' this by not multiplying accumulated forces (i.e. acceleration) by time delta but this doesn't seem correct.

So, my question:

How should a steeringForce for arrival behaviour be generated to account for variable delta time?

Any help gratefully appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I missed the main part of your question. There are many ways to get the result you want, but they do so by different means. The easiest I can come up with is probably to skip the `steeringForce` for now all together and instead just modify the velocity.

We want a vector such that

```
desired_velocity = velocity + correction
```

This is the same as you wrote previously (but for 'steeringForce'):

```
correction = desired_velocity - velocity
```

By doing `velocity + correction` you will immediately get to the desired velocity, which is usually not what you want as it leads to a very jerky motion. Instead, you could clamp the correction to some value which would lead to a smoother motion:

```
len = length(correction)
corr_length = len > max_correction ? max_correction : len
correction = correction/len*corr_length
```

And now you can do

```
velocity += correction
```

This should lead to a somewhat dynamic motion, without oscillation.

---

Explicit time step integration (e.g. an forward Euler in your case) is usually written as

```
new_acceleration = old_acceleration + (delta_t/mass)*force
                                              ^^ note
```

And similarly,

```
new_velocity = old_velocity + delta_t*acceleration
new_position = old_position + delta_t*velocity
```

So to answer your question, you need to multiply by the time step before accumulating:

```
acceleration.add(force.mult(delta_t/mass));
velocity.add(acceleration.mult(delta_t));
location.add(velocity.mult(delta_t));
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response and apologies for delay in replying, I just wanted to query one thing. I can see how avoiding using the steeringForce variable and manipulating velocity directly could provide a fix but it seems to break the whole principle of steering behaviours, which is that you sum forces in order to determine a net steering force which is applied to acceleration which in turn influences velocity which determines location. Is there no way to work within this paradigm in the context of variable time step delta? Ie derive an appropriate steering force?

Comment: @MattGreenhalgh You are correct that this method is less 'physically correct', as we can't achieve this in real life. However, I would say that for many applications this method (and minor alterations of it) would be sufficient. This is really a small PID-controller (see reference) controlling the velocity; you could do the same for the `steeringForce` instead, however it gets a little more involved. As I didn't know your academic level, I wanted to propose the most (to me) straight forward solution first.

Comment: Thanks again for the response. Your instincts on my academic level were about right and I can see from the (very interesting) PID article that arriving at a 'correct' solution is non-trivial. Thanks for your help.