# AI of spaceship's propulsion: land a 3D ship at position=0 and angle=0

Tags: artificial-intelligence, game-physics, path-finding

This is a very difficult problem about how to maneuver a spaceship that can both translate and rotate in 3D, for a space game.

The spaceship has `n` jets placing in various positions and directions.

Transformation of `i`-th jet relative to the CM of spaceship is constant = `Ti`.

- [Transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_transformation) is a tuple of position and orientation (quaternion or matrix 3x3 or, less preferable, Euler angles).
- A transformation can also be denoted by a single matrix 4x4.

In other words, all jet are glued to the ship and cannot rotate.

A jet can exert force to the spaceship only in direction of its axis (green).
As a result of glue, the axis rotated along with the spaceship.

[image]

All jets can exert force (vector,`Fi`) at a certain magnitude (scalar,`fi`) :
`i`-th jet can exert force (`Fi`= `axis` x `fi`) only within range `min_i<= fi <=max_i`.
Both `min_i` and `max_i` are constant with known value.

To be clear, unit of `min_i`,`fi`,`max_i` is Newton.
**Ex.** If the range doesn't cover 0, it means that the jet can't be turned off.

The spaceship's mass = `m` and inertia tensor = `I`.
The spaceship's current transformation = `Tran0`, velocity = `V0`, angularVelocity = `W0`.

The spaceship physic body follows well-known physic rules :-
`Torque=r x F`
`F=ma`
`angularAcceleration = I^-1 x Torque`
`linearAcceleration = m^-1 x F`

`I` is different for each direction, but for the sake of simplicity, it has the same value for every direction (sphere-like).   Thus, `I` can be thought as a scalar instead of matrix 3x3.

### **Question**

How to control all jets (all `fi`) to land the ship with position=0 and angle=0?
**Math-like specification:** Find function of `fi(time)` that take minimum time to reach `position=(0,0,0)`, `orient=identity` with final `angularVelocity` and `velocity` = zero.

More specifically, what are names of technique or related algorithms to solve this problem?

### My research (1 dimension)

If the universe is 1D (thus, no rotation), the problem will be easy to solve.
( Thank  [Gavin Lock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/583195/gavin-lock), https://stackoverflow.com/a/40359322/3577745 )

First, find the value `MIN_BURN=sum{min_i}/m` and `MAX_BURN=sum{max_i}/m`.

Second, think in opposite way, assume that `x=0` (position) and `v=0` at `t=0`,
  then create two parabolas with `x''=MIN_BURN` and  `x''=MAX_BURN`.
  (The 2nd derivative is assumed to be constant for a period of time, so it is parabola.)

The only remaining work is to join two parabolas together.
The red dash line is where them join.

[image]

In the period of time that `x''=MAX_BURN`, all `fi=max_i`.
In the period of time that `x''=MIN_BURN`, all `fi=min_i`.

It works really well for 1D, but in 3D, the problem is far more harder.

**Note:**
Just a rough guide pointing me to a correct direction is really appreciated.
I don't need a perfect AI, e.g. it can take a little more time than optimum.
I think about it for more than 1 week, still find no clue.

**Other attempts / opinions**

- I don't think machine learning like neural network is appropriate for this case.
- Boundary-constrained-least-square-optimisation may be useful but I don't know how to fit my two hyper-parabola to that form of problem.
- This may be solved by using many iterations, but how?
- I have searched NASA's website, but not find anything useful.
- The feature may exist in "Space Engineer" game.
- ***Commented by Logman:*** Knowledge in mechanical engineering may help.
- ***Commented by AndyG:*** It is a motion planning problem with [nonholonomic constraints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonholonomic_system).  It could be solved by [Rapidly exploring random tree (RRTs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapidly-exploring_random_tree), theory around [Lyapunov equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_equation), and [Linear quadratic regulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear%E2%80%93quadratic_regulator).
- ***Commented by John Coleman:*** This seems more like [optimal control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_control) than AI.

**Edit: "Near-0 assumption" (optional)**

- In *most* case, AI (to be designed) run continuously (i.e. called every time-step).
- Thus, with the AI's tuning, `Tran0` is *usually* near-identity, `V0` and `W0` are *usually* not so different from 0, e.g. `|Seta0|<30 degree`,`|W0|<5 degree per time-step` .
- I think that AI based on this assumption would work OK in *most* case.   Although not perfect, it can be considered as a correct solution (I started to think that without this assumption, this question might be too hard).
- I faintly feel that this assumption may enable some tricks that use some "linear"-approximation.

---

---

### The 2nd Alternative Question - "Tune 12 Variables" (easier)

**The above question might also be viewed as followed :-**

I want to tune all six `values` and six `values'` (1st-derivative) to be 0, using lowest amount of time-steps.

Here is a table show a possible situation that AI can face:-

[image]

The **Multiplier table** stores `inertia^-1 * r` and `mass^-1` from the original question.

The **Multiplier** and **Range** are constant.

Each timestep, the AI will be asked to pick a tuple of values `fi` that must be in the range `[min_i,max_i]` for every `i+1`-th jet.
**Ex.** From the table, AI can pick `(f0=1,f1=0.1,f2=-1)`.

Then, the caller will use `fi` to multiply with the **Multiplier table** to get `values''`.
`Px''   = f0*0.2+f1*0.0+f2*0.7`
`Py''   = f0*0.3-f1*0.9-f2*0.6`
`Pz''   = ....................`
`SetaX''= ....................`
`SetaY''= ....................`
`SetaZ''= f0*0.0+f1*0.0+f2*5.0`

After that, the caller will update all `values'` with formula `values' += values''`.
`Px'    +=  Px''`
`.................`
`SetaZ' +=  SetaZ''`

Finally, the caller will update all `values` with formula `values += values'`.
`Px    +=  Px'`
`.................`
`SetaZ +=  SetaZ'`

AI will be asked only once for each time-step.

The objective of AI is to return tuples of `fi` (can be different for different time-step), to make `Px`,`Py`,`Pz`,`SetaX`,`SetaY`,`SetaZ`,`Px'`,`Py'`,`Pz'`,`SetaX'`,`SetaY'`,`SetaZ'` = 0 (or very near),
by using least amount of time-steps as possible.

I hope providing another view of the problem will make it easier.
It is not the exact same problem, but I feel that a solution that can solve this version can bring me very close to the answer of the original question.

An answer for this alternate question can be very useful.

---

---

### The 3rd Alternative Question - "Tune 6 Variables" (easiest)

This is a lossy simplified version of the previous alternative.

The only difference is that the world is now 2D, `Fi` is also 2D (x,y).

Thus I have to tune only `Px`,`Py`,`SetaZ`,`Px'`,`Py'`,`SetaZ'`=0, by using least amount of time-steps as possible.

An answer to this easiest alternative question can be considered useful.

Comment: It's simple you just take 1d solution expand it to n-D solution and fold it to 3d ;)

Comment: @Logman  I can't, each axis will interfere with each other.  Ex. 1st jet want to help to push the ship to left, but its force make the ship rotate clockwise, so the 2nd jet has to help about the rotation which also has side-effect in linear velocity, and so on.    I think each axis is not independent from each other.

Comment: That was a little joke. Just a simple Idea as every jet add some torque and force to your object like T(o) = Sum(a(j)T(j)) and F(o) = Sum(a(j)F(j)) you probably can find "a" series that will satisfy the equation.

Comment: @Logman  XD.    Roughly speaking, there are two equations from 2 parabolas.   I have to find the "dash red line" too.   Moreover, F is not constant, it can be changed by time.  Most case in 1D, it changes at least once (`max_i` <-> `min_i`).  I doubt it might be changed more than once in 3D ( and the value can be in between `min_i`  and `max_i` , only this part can be fit into your model).   Thus, it is not that simple.

Comment: Probably there is a whole 2d plane of solutions that will meet your requirements and not just one point or line. As I see it one jet can't change it force or torque only a factor "a" where a is the same for jet F and T (but I could be wrong here and a is more complex then that). ex. a=0 jet is off a=1 jet is full on;

Comment: @Logman Agree, there may usually be infinite solutions on a plane (hyper surface?).   I allow that jets can exert force in a fraction, e.g. 37% on.  Anything in range [`min_i` ,`max_i`] is allowed.

Comment: Probably some one with mechanical engineering degree could solved your problem as they study such movements.

Comment: Do the jets have a min burn time? As pulse rate modulation can overcome the `min_i` restriction. I would also add that there may be many configurations without a solution, and that there be at least 2 jets for there to be a solution.

Comment: Also there will be configurations that provide solutions only for a subset of all possible starting conditions. And on pulse modulation, as you do not have a fuel limit and thus no time limit the `max_i` constraint can also be ignored.

Comment: @Blindman67   For simplicity, `Fi` can be changed at will with no delay, if that is what you asked.    For simplicity again, there is no fuel limit. - a jet can exert `max_i` as long as AI wants.  .....  I agree that sometimes there is no solution.  In those cases, AI should do "its best".  .....   "pulse rate modulation" = on/off quickly and repeatly?   Concept of "on/off" here is replaced by adjusting `Fi` freely within the range, and the range [`min_i`,`max_i`] doesn't have to cover `0`.   .... Thank, I will improve the question.

Comment: but `min_i` is meaningless by running jet1 at `min_i`  for 1 sec is the same as running jet1 at `min_i / 2` for two seconds. The importance is that jets can be turned on/off and it is not the min thrust a jet can produce but the balance of thrust between all jets. If you need 1/100th of the power of jet2 from jet1 you fire jet1 for 1/100sec to jet2 1sec. Also if there was a error range in end condition zero V and w (angular) Zero makes it too hard.

Comment: @Blindman67   When range [`min_i`,`max_i`] = [1,2], the jet can't be "turned off" (`Fi=0`) in your definition because it will become out of range.     I understand your trick.  Sorry if I wasn't clear.  I will improve it.  .........  I don't understand "If you need 1/100th of the power of jet2 ... 1sec". ..... Yes, it is also too hard for me.

Comment: This is what's called a motion planning problem with nonholonomic constraints. You can use something simple like a rapidly exploring random tree, or a little more complicated like control theoretic solutions for doing lyapunov equations

Comment: @AndyG After your comment, I google some of them, thank for nice keywords!  I can smell solution there.  So excited!

Comment: No problem. I could write a whole paper explaining RRTs in this post, but it's probably better that you read the literature yourself. The control theory stuff is a little out there for me, but aligns a little better with the mathematical statement you've provided. For that you could look into something called a Linear quadratic regulator.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the jets in your simulation can't be stopped? It would make much more sense (at least in my opinion) if `min_i` were the minimal thrust **when turned on**. Besides, unless they are switching off after landing, you should consider the friction between the surface of the planet and the spaceship too ;)

Comment: @Bob__  In my opinion : 1. My (strange?) rule about `min_i` will not make designing the AI much harder.   2. Such rule will make the AI work OK even while some jets are *partially* malfunctioning.   3. Such rule will allow me to adapt the AI to situation that external force != 0.    ........  Yes, I will finally have to cope with that friction later.  The question is already too hard, so I just exclude that feature, i.e. I agree.

Comment: Good points. I like #3, so you can consider forces that the AI _can't_ control (but with a predictable behavior), such as (increasing) gravity or a leak from a pressurized gas tank...

Comment: This sounds like a fascinating problem, which seems to be more like a project for a graduate student in computer science than a Stack Overflow question. I'm surprised that it hasn't been closed as too broad.

Comment: @John Coleman Ha ha, thank to think that I am that young.    It is actually a part of my first 3D game using Bullet (Physic Engine).  After I created it using Entity-Component, learn glsl, make it runable, I thought "This feature would be relatively easy, because it is gameplay!", but I was seriously wrong.   However, it is good to know that I can hire a graduated student for this job.  Do you know how much I should offer, e.g. if I hired you?

Comment: @hek2mgl   About your edit of my question, my research is really 1 dimension, not 2 dimension.  Thus, I rollbacked it.  From the graph, the vertical axis is 1D-displacement, and the horizontal axis is time.  Thank for your interest and concern.

Comment: @javaLover I was thinking more like this would make an interesting research problem for a graduate student pursuing an advanced degree. Most people with an undergraduate degree in computer science wouldn't have the requisite skill set. As a guess on my part, this seems more like optimal control than AI: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_control

Comment: @John Coleman  Thank for sharing.  It is good to know why I have to search for extra knowledge periodically, sometimes with unexpected difficulty.  Also, thank for the link, it looks useful.  I will quote yours in the question. : )

Comment: @AndyG Your comments seem to be the most useful so far.  You can post them again as a short answer.  Thank.

Comment: No promises that I will find the time to write a full answer being that I'm traveling and on mobile. Perhaps in a few days. Really I would just describe how to apply an RRT here. Have you been able to read up on it?

Comment: @AndyG You already helped me a lot.  I have to read some certain Math books first to fully understand the keywords that you suggested.

Comment: "On May 14, 2015, the source code for Space Engineers was made freely available on GitHub to the public." If you believe that game already contains this logic, that should be your starting place.

Comment: The "lunar lander" problem, which is a sub-problem of this more general question, generated lots of scientific papers, see [google results](https://www.google.de/search?q=lunar+lander+programming+optimization)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll try to keep this short and sweet.

One approach that is often used to solve these problems in simulation is a [Rapidly-Exploring Random Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapidly-exploring_random_tree). To give at least a little credibility to my post, I'll admit I studied these, and motion planning was my research lab's area of expertise (probabilistic motion planning).

The canonical paper to read on these is Steven LaValle's [Rapidly-exploring random trees: A new tool for path planning](http://msl.cs.uiuc.edu/%7Elavalle/papers/Lav98c.pdf), and there have been a million papers published since that all improve on it in some way.

First I'll cover the most basic description of an RRT, and then I'll describe how it changes when you have dynamical constraints. I'll leave fiddling with it afterwards up to you:

### Terminology

#### "Spaces"

The state of your spaceship can be described by its 3-dimension position (x, y, z) and its 3-dimensional rotation (alpha, beta, gamma) (I use those greek names because those are the [Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles)).

**state space** is all possible positions and rotations your spaceship can inhabit. Of course this is infinite.

**collision space** are all of the "invalid" states. i.e. realistically impossible positions. These are states where your spaceship is in collision with some obstacle (With other bodies this would also include collision with itself, for example planning for a length of chain). Abbreviated as C-Space.

**free space** is anything that is not collision space.

### General Approach (no dynamics constraints)

For a body without dynamical constraints the approach is fairly straightforward:

1. Sample a state
2. Find nearest neighbors to that state
3. Attempt to plan a route between the neighbors and the state

I'll briefly discuss each step

#### Sampling a state

Sampling a state in the most basic case means choosing at random values for each entry in your state space. If we did this with your space ship, we'd randomly sample for x, y, z, alpha, beta, gamma across all of their possible values (uniform random sampling).

Of course way more of your space is obstacle space than free space typically (because you usually confine your object in question to some "environment" you want to move about inside of). So what is very common to do is to take the bounding cube of your environment and sample positions within it (x, y, z), and now we have a lot higher chance to sample in the free space.

In an RRT, you'll sample randomly *most* of the time. But with some probability you will actually choose your next sample to be your goal state (play with it, start with 0.05). This is because you need to periodically test to see if a path from start to goal is available.

#### Finding nearest neighbors to a sampled state

You chose some fixed integer > 0. Let's call that integer `k`. Your `k` nearest neighbors are nearby in state space. That means you have some **distance metric** that can tell you how far away states are from each other. The most basic distance metric is [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance), which only accounts for physical distance and doesn't care about rotational angles (because in the simplest case you can rotate 360 degrees in a single timestep).

Initially you'll only have your starting position, so it will be the only candidate in the nearest neighbor list.

### Planning a route between states

This is called **local planning**. In a real-world scenario you know where you're going, and along the way you need to dodge other people and moving objects. We won't worry about those things here. In our planning world we assume the universe is static but for us.

What's most common is to assume some linear interpolation between the sampled state and its nearest neighbor. The neighbor (i.e. a node already in the tree) is moved along this linear interpolation bit by bit until it either reaches the sampled configuration, or it travels some maximum **distance** (recall your distance metric).

What's going on here is that *your tree is growing towards the sample*. When I say that you step "bit by bit" I mean you define some "delta" (a really small value) and move along the linear interpolation that much each *timestep*. At each point you check to see if you the new state is in collision with some obstacle. If you hit an obstacle, you keep the last valid configuration as part of the tree (don't forget to store the edge somehow!) So what you'll need for a local planner is:

- Collision checking
- how to "interpolate" between two states (for your problem you don't need to worry about this because we'll do something different).
- A physics simulation for timestepping ([Euler integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method) is quite common, but less stable than something like [Runge-Kutta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods). Fortunately you already have a physics model!

### Modification for dynamical constraints

Of course if we assume you can linearly interpolate between states, we'll violate the physics you've defined for your spaceship. So we modify the RRT as follows:

- Instead of sampling random states, we sample random *controls* and apply said controls for a fixed time period (or until collision).

Before, when we sampled random states, what we were really doing was choosing a direction (in state space) to move. Now that we have constraints, we randomly sample our controls, which is effectively the same thing, except we're guaranteed not to violate our constraints.

After you apply your control for a fixed time interval (or until collision), you add a node to the tree, with the control stored on the edge. Your tree will grow very fast to explore the space. This control application replaces linear interpolation between tree states and sampled states.

#### Sampling the controls

You have `n` jets that individually have some min and max force they can apply. Sample within that min and max force *for each jet*.

#### Which node(s) do I apply my controls to?

Well you can choose at random, or your can bias the selection to choose nodes that are nearest to your goal state (need the distance metric). This biasing will try to grow nodes closer to the goal over time.

Now, with this approach, you're unlikely to *exactly* reach your goal, so you need to define some definition of "close enough". That is, you will use your distance metric to find nearest neighbors to your goal state, and then test them for "close enough". This "close enough" metric can be different than your distance metric, or not. If you're using Euclidean distance, but it's very important that you goal configuration is also rotated properly, then you may want to modify the "close enough" metric to look at angle differences.

What is "close enough" is entirely up to you. Also something for you to tune, and there are a million papers that try to get you a lot closer in the first place.

### Conclusion

This random sampling may sound ridiculous, but your tree will grow to explore your free space very quickly. See some youtube videos on RRT for path planning. We can't guarantee something called "probabilistic completeness" with dynamical constraints, but it's usually "good enough". Sometimes it'll be possible that a solution does not exist, so you'll need to put some logic in there to stop growing the tree after a while (20,000 samples for example)

#### More Resources:

Start with these, and then start looking into their citations, and then start looking into who is citing them.

- [Kinodynamic RRT*](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=6631299)
- [RRT-Connect](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/844730/?arnumber=844730)

Comment: Thank for this stunning answer. It would take time to digest, but I am sure that it will finally lead me to the legendary AI that I always dream of. Thank for putting a lot of great effort into this.  You are surely an expert in the field. (four A4 printed :D)

Comment: +1. This is a very good answer and is exactly what I was referring to in my own answer when I mentioned "stochastic decision trees". There is still considerable complexity in the *"local planner"* if you want to do better than random sampling. Sampling the controls instead of the state space allows you to bypass solving the physics directly, but you can expect an enormous tree size. I'm curious to see runtimes and convergence rates; so please share with us if you ever implement this.

Comment: @SpecialSauce: Thanks! I certainly agree with you regarding the local planner. In fact, I think any portion of the solver could be arbitrarily complex, and in fact that's where all the research was during my time as a grad student; someone would make one portion more complex to see if the increased computation made it planning faster as a result (it's all heuristics, really). Most of the time, simple won out because of sheer numbers.

Convergence rates, as you probably know, are very problem dependent, as well as parameter dependent. Often you tune a solver for a specific problem. Continued-

Comment: @SpecialSauce: Runtimes were/are surprisingly fast for RRT. Like, scary fast. Again, it's problem dependent (Bug-trap esque problems with very narrow entry ways in realspace always pose a problem), but in general it's fast (I mean, we can do a million random samples in no time flat these days, not to mention the work that's going into parallelising these things by partitioning the physical space for example).Certainly trees can grow large. One of the stopping conditions for the solver is often when the tree reached a certain max # of nodes.

Comment: @AndyG: Fascinating; thanks so much for these insights.

Answer (score 5):

This is not an answer, but it's too long to place as a comment.

First of all, a real solution will involve both [linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Algorithms) (for multivariate optimization with constraints that will be used in many of the substeps) as well as techniques used in [trajectory optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory_optimization) and/or control theory. This is a very complex problem and if you can solve it, you could have a job at any company of your choosing. The only thing that could make this problem worse would be friction (drag) effects or external body gravitation effects. A real solution would also ideally use Verlet integration or 4th order Runge Kutta, which offer improvements over the Euler integration you've implemented here.

Secondly, I believe your *"2nd Alternative Version"* of your question above has omitted the rotational influence on the positional displacement vector you add into the position at each timestep. While the jet axes all remain fixed relative to the frame of reference of the ship, they do **not** remain fixed relative to the global coordinate system you are using to land the ship (at global coordinate `[0, 0, 0]`). Therefore the `[Px', Py', Pz']` vector (calculated from the ship's frame of reference) must undergo appropriate rotation in all 3 dimensions prior to being applied to the global position coordinates.

Thirdly, there are some implicit assumptions you failed to specify. For example, one dimension should be defined as the "landing depth" dimension and negative coordinate values should be prohibited (unless you accept a fiery crash). I developed a mockup model for this in which I assumed `z` dimension to be the landing dimension. This problem is very sensitive to initial state and the constraints placed on the jets. All of my attempts using your example initial conditions above failed to land. For example, in my mockup (without the 3d displacement vector rotation noted above), the jet constraints only allow for rotation in one direction on the z-axis. So if `aZ` becomes negative at any time (which is often the case) the ship is actually forced to complete another full rotation on that axis before it can even try to approach zero degrees again. Also, without the 3d displacement vector rotation, you will find that `Px` will only go negative using your example initial conditions and constraints, and the ship is forced to either crash or diverge farther and farther onto the negative x-axis as it attempts to maneuver. The only way to solve this is to truly incorporate rotation or allow for sufficient positive and negative jet forces.

However, even when I relaxed your min/max force constraints, I was unable to get my mockup to land successfully, demonstrating how complex planning will probably be required here. Unless it is possible to completely formulate this problem in linear programming space, I believe you will need to incorporate advanced planning or stochastic decision trees that are "smart" enough to continually use rotational methods to reorient the most flexible jets onto the currently most necessary axes.

Lastly, as I noted in the comments section, "On May 14, 2015, the source code for Space Engineers was made freely available on GitHub to the public." If you believe that game already contains this logic, that should be your starting place. However, I suspect you are bound to be disappointed. Most space game landing sequences simply take control of the ship and do not simulate "real" force vectors. Once you take control of a 3-d model, it is very easy to predetermine a 3d spline with rotation that will allow the ship to land softly and with perfect bearing at the predetermined time. Why would any game programmer go through this level of work for a landing sequence? This sort of logic could control ICBM missiles or planetary rover re-entry vehicles and it is simply overkill IMHO for a game (unless the very purpose of the game is to see if you can land a damaged spaceship with arbitrary jets and constraints without crashing).

Comment: In general, we delete answers that start with "This is not an answer" - but all answers here are probably destined for deletion, the question is probably far too broad.

Comment: @Aaron Hall  I changed the question to  "what are names of technique or related algorithms to solve this problem?"  In your opinion, does it become a little less broad ?

Comment: I'm going to defer to more experienced mods, as I'm new, and I don't want to mess this one up. I've already given them notice.

Answer (score 2):

I can introduce another technique into the mix of (awesome) answers proposed.

It lies more in AI, and provides close-to-optimal solutions. It's called [Machine Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning), more specifically [Q-Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-learning). It's surprisingly easy to implement but hard to get right.

The advantage is  that the learning can be done *offline*, so the algorithm can then be *super* fast when used.

You could do the learning when the ship is built or when something happens to it (thruster destruction, large chunks torn away...).

---

### Optimality

I observed you're looking for near-optimal solutions. Your method with parabolas is good for optimal control. What you did is this:

- **Observe the state** of the system.
- For every state (coming in too fast, too slow, heading away, closing in etc.) you devised an action (**apply a strategy**) that will bring the system into a state closer to the goal.
- Repeat

This is pretty much intractable for a human in 3D (too many cases, will drive you nuts) *however* a machine may learn where to split the parabolas in every dimensions, and devise an optimal strategy by itself.

THe Q-learning works very similarly to us:

- **Observe the (secretized) state** of the system
- Select an action based on a **strategy**

  - If this action brought the system into a desirable state (closer to the goal), mark the action/initial state as more desirable
- Repeat

---

### Discretize your system's state.

For each state, have a map intialized quasi-randomly, which maps every state to an Action (this is the **strategy**). Also assign a desirability to each state (initially, zero everywhere and 1000000 to the target state (X=0, V=0).

- Your state would be your 3 positions, 3 angles, 3translation speed,  and three rotation speed.
- Your actions can be any combination of thrusters

---

### Training

Train the AI (offline phase):

- Generate many diverse situations
- Apply the strategy
- Evaluate the new state
- Let the algo (see links above) reinforce the selected strategies' desirability value.

---

### Live usage in the game

After some time, a global strategy for navigation emerges. You then store it, and during your game loop you simply sample your strategy and apply it to each situation as they come up.

The strategy may still learn during this phase, but probably more slowly (because it happens real-time). (Btw, I dream of a game where the AI would learn from every user's feedback so we could collectively train it ^^)

---

Try this in a simple 1D problem, it devises a strategy remarkably quickly (a few seconds).

In 2D I believe excellent results could be obtained in an hour.

For 3D... You're looking at overnight computations. There's a few thing to try and accelerate the process:

1. Try to **never 'forget'** previous computations, and feed them as an initial 'best guess' strategy. Save it to a file!
2. You might drop some states (like ship roll maybe?) without losing much navigation optimality but increasing computation speed greatly. Maybe change referentials so the ship is always on the X-axis, this way you'll drop x&y dimensions!
3. States more frequently encountered will have a reliable and very optimal strategy. Maybe normalize the state to make your ship state always close to a 'standard' state?
4. Typically rotation speeds intervals may be bounded safely (you don't want a ship tumbling wildely, so the strategy will always be to "un-wind" that speed). Of course rotation angles are additionally bounded.
5. You can also probably discretize non-linearly the positions because farther away from the objective, precision won't affect the strategy much.

Answer (score 1):

For these kind of problems there are two techniques available: bruteforce search and heuristics. Bruteforce means to recognize the problem as a blackbox with input and output parameters and the aim is to get the right input parameters for winning the game. To program such a bruteforce search, the gamephysics runs in a simulation loop (physics simulation) and via stochastic search (minimax, alpha-beta-prunning) every possibility is tried out. The disadvantage of bruteforce search is the high cpu consumption.

The other techniques utilizes knowledge about the game. Knowledge about motion primitives  and about evaluation. This knowledge is programmed with normal computerlanguages like C++ or Java. The disadvantage of this idea is, that it is often difficult to grasp the knowledge.

The best practice for solving spaceship navigation is to combine both ideas into a hybrid system. For programming sourcecode for this concrete problem I estimate that nearly 2000 lines of code are necessary. These kind of problems are normaly done within huge projects with many programmers and takes about 6 months.

Comment: This is a good article as an introduction for some chapters of AI textbook. It is very-wide. If I asked how to code AI for an enemy in 2D platformer, or real-time strategy game, this answer would still be compatible. It would be nice if this answer can be a bit more focus on this problem more specifically. For example, minimax is not suitable for this case, at least in my opinion.  Thank for the figure!

Comment: You're right, the answer is more general. A detailed answer would consistics of runable code, which not only simulates the spaceship game but also implements a solver for that game. I think that coding itself would be offtopic here ...

Comment: Runable code is not necessary, I agree that it might be too much to expect. If you don't have time to draft pseudo-algorithm, some specific keywords or rough idea can still be very useful. For example, an answer containing rough idea like  http://stackoverflow.com/a/40359322/3577745 is a very good way to answer my question. : )